# Read data from Wii-balanceboard

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth, hid, wii-balanceboard

Im trying to get the output from a Wii Fit (balance board). I can find the device via the C++ Bluetooth enumerators but attempts to connect via a windows socket are failing.

Im wondering if anyone has had success in such a direction (C++, windows) I'd love to hear how you did it.

Comment: Just a random idea - have you looked into the Wiimote libraries? I wouldn't be surprised if connecting to the balance board is somewhat similar.

Comment: .. am exploring 'WiiYourself'...

Comment: Use gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Wii Balance Board is a HID device.  To understand communications with the Balance Board, you need to know a little bit about Bluetooth HID.  There's good information on WiiBrew about the [Wiimote](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wiimote) and the [Wii Balance Board](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wii_Balance_Board).

I don't think you can use Windows Sockets to connect to a HID device.  The Windows Socket Bluetooth interface only allows you to connect to RFCOMM-based services.  HID is based on L2CAP which is further down the Bluetooth protocol stack.  There's some information [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa931855.aspx) about that limitation.

If you're just looking to hack around with it, you can try [Bluecove](http://bluecove.org/) for Java.  You may be able to do something using another stack (for example, Widcomm).  If you're locked in to Windows and C++, you may have to look into writing an custom HID driver for the Balance Board.

Comment: Yeah.. i was wondering about whether it was a HID device (is that redundant?).

Comment: I think that he is speaking about Windows XP/Vista/7 while your MSDN link is about Windows CE 6.0 R3.

Comment: I was under the impression that the limitation held for desktop Windows as well as Windows CE.

Comment: Yes this limitation remains, frankly I don't understand MS why are not offering support for L2CAP too. You are right with Windows SDK API you cannot access the L2CAP layer.

Comment: Yes both Win32 and WinCE don't support L2CAP sockets. Both provide a driver (kernel on Win32 at least) API.

Answer (score 1):

As pwc said there is a limitation in the MS Bluetooth API, so with sockets you cannot have something else except RFCOMM, but this doesn't mean you cannot go down at L2CAP layer. What you have to do is to implement a client profile driver and you can use as starting point an article from MSDN: [Creating a L2CAP Client Connection to a Remote Device](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff536674%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and vice-versa: [Accepting L2CAP Connections in a Bluetooth Profile Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff536572%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Next of course as pwc said you have to study Bluetooth HID and WiiBrew for the communication protocol.

Also a good document to read is [Bluetooth Wireless Technology FAQ - 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487349.aspx) which states clear that it is possible to have L2CAP connections with Microsoft Bluetooth stack driver. Of course not with sockets.

Answer (score 1):

When using HID on a Bluetooth device there is generally *no* need to create a L2CAP connection directly.  All(???) of the Bluetooth stacks on Win32 have support for Bluetooth HID and provide access to the HID stream/control through the native Windows HID API.  No (direct) L2CAP required! :-)

On WinCE there is built-in support for Bluetooth HID also, but I'm not sure there's a way to access a HID API.

That's how Brian Peek's wiimore library works -- it uses the HID API.  The good thing about that is that one gets supports for all(?) the Bluetooth stacks that way -- they each support HID devices via the Windows HID API, whereas to use L2CAP directly one would have to support each of the stacks' APIs... (That's if they have one! BlueSoleil has no L2CAP API as far as I can see).

So, on Win32 one should just pair with the device and check that the HID checkbox is checked on its Bluetooth Service control panel tab (whichever Bluetooth stack is in use).  In my 32feet.NET library one can discover the device and then ensure that HID is enabled for it with:

```
BluetoothDeviceInfo[] list = btCli.DiscoveryDevices();
var deviceInfo = list[n]; // Select the correct device
deviceInfo.SetServiceState(BluetoothService.HumanInterfaceDevice, true);
```

(That should work on MSFT and BlueSoleil; there's no API for that on Widcomm AFAIK -- although when paired it might be automatically enabled anyway).

The one possible exception case is that apparently some devices are not fully compliant with the Bluetooth/HID specs, I'm told the PS3 blu-ray controller is like that.  Then one might want to try L2CAP connections directly -- however its likely that the stack's support for HID will interfere with third-party applications trying to provide the same service...

Comment: FWIW: I used the 'wii yourself' library and was able to get weight, balance, etc from the balance board using a simple MFC app.